# Take Negation of Func<double[], double[]>

Tags: c#, func

I have the following function

```
public Func<double[], double> Function { get; set; }
this.Function = (x) => 
    Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x[0] - 1, 2)) + Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(x[1] - 2, 2));
```

and the gradient which is the partial derivatives of the function above

```
public Func<double[], double[]> Gradient { get; set; } 
this.Gradient = (x) => new double[] 
{
    // df/dx = -2 * e^(-(x - 1)²)(x - 1).
    -2 * Math.Exp(-Math.Pow(x[0] - 1, 2)) * (x[0] - 1),

    // df/dy = -e^(-1/2(y - 2)²) * (y - 2).
    -Math.Exp(-0.5 * Math.Pow(x[1] - 2, 2)) * (x[1] - 2)
};
```

To take the negation of the `function` I can do

```
Func<double[], double> oldFunc = this.Function;
this.Function = (x) => -oldFunc(x);
```

My question is, how can take the negation of each of the partial derivatives in `gradient` the same way?

Comment: Why the down vote? I thought good questions were what this site is all about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;    

Func<double[], double[]> oldFunc = this.Gradient;
this.Gradient = (x) => oldFunc(x).Select( y => -y).ToArray();
```

Comment: This does not work. 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'double[]' to 'System.Func<double[],double[]>''...

Comment: This compiles and runs in LINQPad without problems, so you probably screwed up somewhere when you copy-pasted it…

Comment: @Killercam - think you may have mistyped (perhaps missing the `(x) => ` in the `this.Gradient = (x) => oldFunc(x).Select( y => -y).ToArray();` line?)